# The "" file does not exist or is not readable

Tags: laravel

I am having some issue while trying to upload multiple images on the back end in Laravel. I have a simple form with an input field and a multiple attribute that should upload an array of images in the database but whatever I try, I get the same error 'The "" file does not exist or is not readable'. I checked the names in the input field and they are the same as the name in the file() method. Any help is appreciated.

PS: Am a newbie to Laravel and PHP...

ProductController:

```
foreach($request->file('images')->store('images') as $images) {
            $product->images()->create([
                'images' => $images
            ]);
        }
```

Blade file:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf

  <h5>Upload Multiple Images</h5>
  <input type="file" multiple name="images" id="images"> Upload Images
</form
```

Comment: for one thing form action is missing. are you using the same route to get and post? That is, from where are you loading the blade file? If for example, you load the view from create method, and then want to upload the form through store method, you would need to include form action pointing to store route via post.

Comment: Adding the action attribute did not help. No, I have a GET route with a create method and a Post route with a store method.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help but I got it working thanks Vikas Katariya post below. I actually use a redirect on my store method which does the trick.. don't know if that's okay to do it like that because I want to redirect the admin to the product detail page when the product is created. When you're creating a product you don't have an ID yet so I can't use the action attribute to 'admin/product/ . $product->id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling File Upload in Laravel's Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033879/handling-file-upload-in-laravels-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try..

```
$input = $request->all();
$datas = [];
if ($request->hasfile('images')) {
foreach ($request->file('images') as $key => $file) {
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
         $file->move(public_path() . '/your path /', $name); //if you want to store image in yopur folder
         $datas[$key] = $name;
         $file = new YourMOdelNAme();
        foreach ($datas as $data) {
           $file->images = $data;
            $file->save();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: please give upvote this answer.THANK YOU @user12408466

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue a few days ago. Hope this helps anyone.

I solved the problem by setting `php_value upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` over the size of my uploaded file.

This is where I found the answer in case you are interested:

> If someone else gets this error and it doesn't turn out to be a permissions issue, check your php.ini...make sure that your upload_max_filesize is as big as your post_max_size. I had 1000M for post_max_size (we deal with some big ol' video files), but only 100M for upload_max_size (I blame my old eyes). The upload would churn for a long time, and then throw the error above.
> https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31249

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28139192)

Comment: @KhalidKhan you are right that was more of a comment than an answer. Sry, I am new to this site

Comment: This worked for me.  Don't care if it's an "answer" or a "comment" since it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upload files using below code

```
$files = $request->file('images');
if($request->hasFile('images'))
{
   foreach ($files as $file) 
     $product->images()->create([
       'images' => $file
     ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

name images array

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf

  <h5>Upload Multiple Images</h5>
  <input type="file" multiple name="images[]" id="images"> Upload Images
</form
```