# Sending file to api endpoint using guzzle and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to use guzzle to send a file to an api endpoint. WebsiteA (laravel) will send a file input to WebsiteB (laravel). The problem is, I'm getting a tmp path only in WebisteB when i check the request and not the whole file. I need to store the file in WebsiteB.

If i dd($request->file('file')) on WebsiteA it returns image below.

[image]

**WebsiteA**

```
public function postContent(Request $request) {
    if($request->file){
        $response = $this->guzzleClient()->post($this->archiving->url . config('archiving.api_post_file_content'),
            [  
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'file',
                        'contents' => $request->file('file'),
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
        return $response->getBody(); 
    }else{
        return 'no file';
    }

}
```

**WebsiteB**

```
public function storeContentFile(Request $request){
    return $request->all(); //returns -> file: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpFEA3.tmp"

    /* if($request->file){ 
        $uploadedFiles=$request->file('file');
        $file_name = time().'.'.$uploadedFiles->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploadedFiles->move('media/content/', $file_name);
       }
    */
    //getting error getClientOriginalName() on string
}
```

Comment: of course it is a temporary path, where is it supposed to store the uploaded file before your script gets to decide what to do with it or not do anything with it? why are you expecting it to not be a temporary path? ... from the PHP manual "Files will, by default be stored in the server's default temporary directory, unless another location has been given with the `upload_tmp_dir` directive in `php.ini`" [PHP Manual - Handling File Uploads - Post method Uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: because i need to store the file in websiteB. How can i store the file ? cause i only got the tmp name. check my updated question thanks @lagbox

Comment: on server b i would do a `if ($request->hasFile(...))` to make sure, but is that the correct way to send that file via guzzle from server A? I have a feeling you trying to pass the `UploadedFile` as the contents is causing it to be converted to a string, which would mean it is returning the temporary filename not the contents of the file ... without code in front of me i am assuming that is what is happening ... hope that helps in some way

Comment: yeah, i checked hasFile and no file. so im not sure what's the right way to do it @lagbox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling File Upload in Laravel's Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033879/handling-file-upload-in-laravels-controller)

Comment: @NicoHaase, I've checked the file and it's present in WebsiteA.  The problem is how do i use guzzle correctly to transfer the file to WebsiteB.

Comment: What makes you think that this does not work as expected? If the request on WebsiteB contains a temporary path, the upload might have worked - have you checked that temporary path for the data stored there?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm getting the error "getClientOriginalName() on string
" . Plus, the file im trying to send is an image, but what i receive (in websiteB) is a tmp path. I want to save the image on websiteB.

Comment: Have you checked whatever is stored at that tmp path? That's how all file uploads in PHP work

Comment: @NicoHaase I've managed to save the tmp file in websiteB. can the tmp file be converted into an image?

Comment: What do you mean by "converted into an image"? What happens if you compare that file, and the source file? Are they the same?

Comment: @NicoHaase no. the source file is an image but the one that got saved was a tmp file with scramble characters in it

Comment: And if you rename the tmp file to `image.png`, it is still not an image? Well, then you should start debugging :)