# How to use foreach for ajax array in Laravel?

Tags: arrays, ajax, laravel

I have an ajax function where I post multiple files in an array. How can store these files? I tried the following code in controller but only the first file is being stored.

```
foreach ($request->photos as $imagefile) {
  $imageName = $imagefile->getClientOriginalName();
  $imagePath = public_path('folder-path/');
  $imagefile->move($imagePath,$imageName);
}
```

also this is how my array looks like
[array from ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW0Un.png)

as @innovin requested.

**Blade File**

`<input name="files[]" type="file" class="form-control" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" multiple id="files">`

`<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="otherUpload()">Update</a>`

````
    function otherUpload(){
      var outputdata = [];
      var fileSelect = document.getElementById('files');
      var files = fileSelect.files;
      var formData = new FormData();
      // Loop through each of the selected files.
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          var file = files[i];
          // Check the file type.
          if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
              continue;
          }
          // Add the file to the request.
          formData.append('photos[]', file, file.name);
      }

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'post-url',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType:'json',
        data: formData,
        success:function(data) {
          if(data.code == 1){
          console.log(data);
          fetchOtherImages();
      }
        }
      });
    }
</script>```
````

Comment: Please update your question with your ajax code and blade file.

Comment: @Innovin just updated. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling File Upload in Laravel's Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033879/handling-file-upload-in-laravels-controller)

Answer (score 0):

you should loop through `$request->file('photos')` instead of `$request->photos`

```php
        if($request->hasfile('photos'))
         {
            foreach($request->file('photos') as $photo)
            {
                $name = $photo->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move(public_path('folder-path'), $name); 
                // to store file in Storage folder:  
                //$file->storeAs('files', $name); 
            }
         }
```

note that he function `GetClientOriginalName()` is used to retrieve the file's original name at the time of upload in laravel, and that'll only be possible if the data is sent as **array** and not as a string. Hence, you must add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` whenever you are creating a form with input fields for files or images.